# How to block a thread until another ends

Tags: android, multithreading, opencv, video-streaming, frame

I am developing an android application which opens a video stream, using the class org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView offered by the opencv libraries, and captures frames from it, in order to process them before they are shown on the screen.

The application is organized in this way:

1. a main thread, which has the OnCameraFrame method, that acquires frame and send it to the thread A, and this method is also responsible for displaying the final frame on screen. So all the processing should be performed after the frame has been acquired, and before it is shown on screen,in "the middle" of this method.
2. the thread A, which saves the frame acquired into a buffer, a BlockingLinkedQueue;
3. the thread B, which takes a frame from the buffer, and send it to the thread responsible for the processing, the thread C;
4. the thread C, which process the frame, and send it to the main thread.

So the question is: how can I block the method OnCameraFrame, so it can't show any frame on the screen, until it has been returned from the last thread (C)? If I don't implement any thing of this type, because of the processing requires a bit of time, I don't see the final frame correctly on the screen.

I hope I have been clear in explaining my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method would be `Thread.join()` but you should normally not call it in the main thread. Instead you should just not show anything in your `onCameraFrame()` but at the end of computation thread C can call e.g. `Activity.runOnUiThread()` with code to show the frame.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid blocking callbacks - depending on the calling thread you may end up with ANR. Add a queue between your callback and processing thread.

I'm not sure why you need so many threads and a blocking queue - make a single thread, create a Handler on this thread and a Handler on the main thread. When you receive a frame in the callback - post it to the processing thread handler, when it is done processing - post results to the main thread handler.